# Need help writing a batch-file

Tags: windows, batch-file

The path to the folder and the format come to the input of the batch file 
file(for example, txt) (as parameters of a batch file). 
The folder must contain different files. 
If such folder does not exist, then write “This folder does not exist” and 
terminate the program. 
If such a folder exists, then find everything in it and in its subfolders 
files of the specified extension for which it is installed 
archive attribute. Output the number of such files in 
console

**[Edit /]**

This is what I have:

```
@echo off
if not exist %1 (echo "This folder does not exist" && pause && exit /B )
set /a count=0
for %%i in (dir %1\*.%2 /A:A /S ) do ( set /a count+=1 )
Echo in the folder %1, found %count% files with extension %2 and attribute 
Archive
pause
```

The final count is incorrect
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the command you are using to invoke the batch file and an example of the directory/file structure you are running this against?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean added screen

Comment: I recommend to use `/A:A-D` if you are interested only in files and ignore all directories. A directory can have also the archive attribute set like a file (because a directory is in file system in real just a special file).

Answer (score 0):

Your line `for %%i in (dir %1\*.%2 /A:A /S ) do ...` is wrong in a few ways.

You want to process the output of a command: add `/f` and single-quoting the command.

You count every line of the output (including header and summary: add `/b` to list just the filenames.

if there are spaces in your parameters, it will fail: use `%~n` to remove any surrounding quotes and quote the full path.

So allthogether, the line should probably be:

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b "%~1\*.%~2" /A:A /S') do ...
```

See `for /?` and `dir /?` for details.

(to be exact, you should also add `"delims="` to get the whole filename instead of just its first word, but as you are just counting the lines, it wouldn't change anything)

Another thing: `if not exist %1 (echo "This folder does not exist"` is suboptimal. If no parameter was given, `%1` is empty, the `if` results in `if not exist (echo` (tries to find a file named `(echo` and the command to be executed would be `"This folder does not exist"` which results in the error message `'"This folder does not exist"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Safer Syntax: `if not exist "%~1" (echo ...`

Answer (score 0):

This in a batch file works for me. One problem is that without the /B option, it is also counting extra records coming back for directories. Your current "for" is actually counting the parts of the statement inside it, not the actual output in running the command.

```
@echo off
cls
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if not exist %1 (echo "This folder does not exist" && pause && exit /B )
set /a count=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir "%1\*.%2" /A:A /S /B') do (
    set /a count+=1
)
Echo in the folder %1, found %count% files with extension %2 and attribute Archive
pause
```